# What type of specialty stores carry flashing for windows and doors? Looking for bottom and top flashing

Tags: doors, windows, flashing

**Context**: Installing new windows and doors. Need to find flashing. For example a flashing pan of 4in x 8 11/16 x 3/4in and 12 ft long.

What type of home improvement or specialty stores carry flashing for windows. The large multi nationals have some, but I am looking for larger sheets of metal or more custom shaped.

Comment: An internet search for `metal supply <your town>` should yield you the answer to this question.

Comment: Your local hvac or (rain) gutter shop will be able to bend up pans and flashing for you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For larger sheets and custom shapes, the usual practice seems to be to buy raw metal stock of the desired thickness, then cut and fold it to shape on site. A bending brake would be the standard tool for making well-controlled bends.

Comment: Funny: when I worked in the Northeast, *everybody* had a brake at their disposal. Now in California, *nobody* seems to own a brake.

Comment: A brake isn't an expensive piece of equipment... So what are the Californians doing instead? Ordering from someone who has one? Beating the metal into shape on an anvil? Using plastic?

Comment: Mostly we order… (we have good relationships with tin bangers, so turnaround is fast). Sometimes it does come to the hammer/anvil method ;)